# detachable generic to generic in eiffel

Tags: eiffel

I have a feature with post-condition as follow:

```
checkValue (k: K): detachable V
do
...
end
ensure
some_post_condition:
    checkKey (Result)
```

And here is prototype of "checkKey":

```
checkKey (v: V): BOOLEAN
```

Since "Result" is type of "detachable V", and I try to pass that as parameter to "checkKey " which only accept type of "V" but not "detachable V", thus it cannot compile.

Here is what compile error says:

```
Argument name: v
Argument position: 1
Formal argument type: Generic #1
Actual argument type: detachable Generic #1
```

How can I convert detachable Generic to Generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options:

1. Change the type of `checkValue` from `detachable V` to `V`.
2. Change the type of the argument of `checkKey` from `V` to `detachable V`.
3. Change the postcondition to read

   - if `Result` should always be attached

     ```
     result_attached: attached Result
     some_post_condition: checkKey (Result)
     ```
   - if `Result` may be detachable (in which case it is considered valid):

     ```
     some_post_condition: attached Result implies checkKey (Result)
     ```